# ReferenceError: Text is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, dom

I use node.js in combination with typescript and I have a class with a method:

```
 createTextSinglelineTextNode(document: Document, infopageVariable: TextSingleline): Text {
     const text: Text = document.createTextNode(infopageVariable.content);
     console.log(text instanceof Text);
     return text;
 }
```

When I try to check whether the instance of the text is Text I get:

```
ReferenceError: Text is not defined
```

I have no clue what the problem could be. I thank you all in advance for your time and possible answers :)

Comment: Is `Document` defined? Maybe you didn't include `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Comment: I use jsdom to create the document and pass it. How can I include the file?

Comment: On the ts documentation it says: 
Note: If --lib is not specified a default list of libraries are injected. The default libraries injected are:
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost